# Easier way to add arguments to an "or" statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements, multiple-conditions

Is there an easier way to do the following without me having to write out `outputbodypixel == everytime`? Ideally I want to pull the data from a list where I can just add `#ebebeb`, `#ececec`, `#212121`.

```
if(outputbodypixel == "#356044" or outputbodypixel == "#22402b" or
   outputbodypixel == "#213f2c" or outputbodypixel == "#356043" or
   outputbodypixel == "#22402c" or outputbodypixel == "#346044"):
    output_body = "green"
elif(outputbodypixel == "#7c3d15" or outputbodypixel == "#493613" or
     outputbodypixel == "#4a3612" or outputbodypixel == "#6a553e" or
     outputbodypixel == "#785735" or outputbodypixel == "#5e4b37" or
     outputbodypixel == "#6a553e" or outputbodypixel == "#86623c" or
     outputbodypixel == "#8b4f0d" or outputbodypixel == "#7c3d14" or
     outputbodypixel == "#6a553d" or outputbodypixel == "#7c3d14" or
     outputbodypixel == "#6a553d" or outputbodypixel == "#7c3d14" or
     outputbodypixel == "#87623c" or outputbodypixel == "#6e3612" or
     outputbodypixel == "#87613c"):
    output_body = "brown"
elif(outputbodypixel == "#8b8b8a" or outputbodypixel == "#8b8b8b" or
     outputbodypixel == "#8b8a8b"):
    output_body = "silver"
else:
    output_body = "NOT DEFINED"
```

I'm using Python 3.x.

Comment: Put all the possible colors (conditions) in a list, then use `if outputbodypixel in color_list:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `in` with a tuple (or a list if you already have one for each case) of all possible values per each condition, it's exactly the same as asking if `outputbodypixel` is one value `or` the other `or` the other etc.

```
if outputbodypixel in ("#356044", "#22402b", "#213f2c", "#356043", "#22402c", "#346044"):
    output_body = "green"
elif outputbodypixel in ("#7c3d15", "#493613", "#4a3612", "#6a553e", "#785735", "#5e4b37", "#6a553e", "#86623c", "#8b4f0d", "#7c3d14", "#6a553d", "#7c3d14", "#6a553d", "#7c3d14", "#87623c", "#6e3612", "#87613c"):
    output_body = "brown"
elif outputbodypixel in ("#8b8b8a", "#8b8b8b", "#8b8a8b"):
    output_body = "silver"
else:
    output_body = "NOT DEFINED"
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Had no idea you could do it this way, exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: My pleasure! if the lists are very big and you need an extra performance  boost, consider using sets instead, which have `O(1)` cost for the `in` operation - as opposed to the `O(n)` cost for tuples or lists.

Answer (score 2):

For a solution that also has solid performance, you could use a `dict` or a `defaultdict` for this. If you use a `defaultdict`, you can pass a source `dict` into the constructor as follows.

```py
from collections import defaultdict


pixel = defaultdict(lambda: 'NOT DEFINED', {
    '#356044': 'green',
    '#22402b': 'green',
    '#7c3d15': 'brown',
    '#8b8b8a': 'silver',
    '#8b8b8b': 'silver'
})

pixel['#356044']
# green

pixel['#8b8b8b']
# silver

pixel['#something-else']
# NOT DEFINED
```

Comment: To my mind this, or something very similar to this, is the cleanest answer.

Answer (score -3):

You could create a function like this:

```
def output(value):
    return f"outputbodypixel == #{value}"

#You can call the function like this:

if output(12345) or output(5678):
    pass
```

This is just so you don't type every time the "outputbodypixel". And if you want to grab the value from a list, just make a for loop inside the created function that iterates through the values of the list. Hope this helps :D

Comment: This is plain wrong, it doesn't answer OPs question. What makes you think that the _string_ `"outputbodypixel == somevalue"` is the same as evaluating the expression `outputbodypixel == somevalue`?